# Is firewalld needed by fail2ban?

Tags: fail2ban

When I install fail2ban, it also installs firewalld. After a reboot, firewalld also starts, enforcing settings on the iptables (dropping most connections accept ssh). This is frustrating as I want to allow https and http. Should I uninstall firewalld, disable it, or alter a service/init.d section? Where is firewalld getting commands from, such as those below.

```
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
#####  much later in the config #########
Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW
```

What is the best approach to this?

As an aside, where does fail2ban store banned IPs and how does it enforce restrictions?

Comment: What is your distribution? This is likely a distribution specific default configuration. Fail2Ban can use iptables directly or Firewalld, among many options.

Comment: Please provide your fail2ban configuration `grep -r "banaction" /etc/fail2ban`

Answer (score 0):

No you can also use ufw if you are on debian or Ubuntu or iptables.

In the fail2ban documentation you will see that you can see the banned ips with `fail2ban-client status "jailname"
You are probably on a redhat or redhat based distribution like centos

You can change the configuration of fail2ban to use iptables directly.

In /etc/fail2ban/jail.local

```
[DEFAULT]

ignoreip = 127.0.0.1/8
bantime = 10m
findtime = 10m
maxretry = 3
backend = auto
usedns = warn
destemail = root@localhost
sendername = Fail2Ban
banaction = iptables-multiport
mta = sendmail
protocol = tcp
chain = INPUT
action_ = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
action_mw = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
            %(mta)s-whois[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s", sendername="%(sendername)s"]
action_mwl = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
            %(mta)s-whois-lines[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s", logpath=%(logpath)s, chain="%(chain)s", sendername="%(sendername)s"]
action = %(action_)s
```

And then restart fail2ban with systemctl restart fail2ban.
Don't uninstall firewalld, it might break things, just stop and disable the service using systemctl.

Then flush all the iptables chains with iptables -F to get rid of the firewalld chains and restart fail2ban again.

Fail2ban uses so called jails to enforce restrictions, if queries the logs of a particular service(for example ssh) and then bans ips which do a lot of failed authentication requests. The jails use filters which are regexs to find malicious behavior in the logs.
See here for more information about it
https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/wiki/How-fail2ban-works

---

You can also allow http and https with firewalld easily

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=http
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=https
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

---

Last option is to uninstall fail2ban and firewalld with the distribution package you used and install it manually
https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/wiki/How-to-test-newer-fail2ban-version-resp.-use-fail2ban-standalone-instance

Comment: The option to install fail2ban is dangerous as ot breaks automatic updates from the distribution. This is an issue that can be solved via configuration, so I would remove that advice.

Comment: Do you have a write up of that?I can't hardly believe that because in most Linux distributions it doesn't matter if you install fail2ban using a package manager or manually

Comment: If you install any software manually you would have to maintain it manually, too. You would need to be aware of any bugs and vulnerabilities or have a regular process for updating everything. That's what the distributions do for you, and that's why manual installations over maintained packages cannot be recommended for the business environments that are on-topic on Server Fault.